# how to start counting only if the next 10 rows is true

Tags: pandas, dataframe

i have a data set like below

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| -1 | 2 | -1 |
| 3 | 2 | 5 |
| 6 | 8 | 4 |
| 4 | 7 | 7 |
| 3 | -1 | 9 |
| -1 | -1 | -1 |
| 1 | 3 | 5 |
| -1 | -1 | -1 |
| 3 | 3 | 2 |
| 2 | 5 | 1 |

how can i obtain the sum of columns A, B, C only when the values are >0, 2 rows consecutively, where row that contains 1,3,5 will be ignored since the next row is <0

i tried

```
df["D"] = df.apply(lambda x: (A>0) and (B>0) and (C>0),axis=1)
```

but row that contains 1,3,5 will be calculated

I m expecting rows that only contains value>0, 2 rows consecutively, are sum up.

edited: expected output

| A | B | C | sum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| -1 | 2 | -1 | 46 |
| 3 | 2 | 5 | 16 |
| 6 | 8 | 4 |  |
| 4 | 7 | 7 |  |
| 3 | -1 | 9 |  |
| -1 | -1 | -1 |  |
| 1 | 3 | 5 |  |
| -1 | -1 | -1 |  |
| 3 | 3 | 2 |  |
| 2 | 5 | 1 |  |

Comment: Can you provide the exact expected output for clarity?

Comment: Please edit your question as suggested by mozway since I cannot understand what you want.

Answer (score 1):

The exact expected output is unclear, but assuming you want A+B+C for rows for which all values are positive, at least for two consecutive rows, you could use:

```
# isentify rows with at least one value ≤ 0
m = df.lt(0).any(axis=1)
# only keep positive rows that form groups of 2 of more consecutive rows
df['sum'] = df.loc[df.groupby(m.cumsum()).transform('size').gt(2)&~m].sum(axis=1)
```

Alternatively:

```
m = df.gt(0).all(axis=1)
m2 = m & (m.shift(1, fill_value=True) | m.shift(-1, fill_value=True))
df['sum'] = df.where(m2).sum(axis=1, min_count=1)
```

Output:

```
   A  B  C   sum
0 -1  2 -1   NaN
1  3  2  5  10.0
2  6  8  4  18.0
3  4  7  7  18.0
4  3 -1  9   NaN
5 -1 -1 -1   NaN
6  1  3  5   NaN
7 -1 -1 -1   NaN
```

If you rather want the sum per column, excluding the rows with negative values or lone positive rows:

```
m = df.lt(0).any(axis=1)
df.loc[df.groupby(m.cumsum()).transform('size').gt(2)&~m].sum()
```

Output:

```
A    13
B    17
C    16
dtype: int64
```

If want a sum per row, but considering the values to keep per column (i.e. the first `2` in col `B` would be kept since it's part of a stretch of more than one value::

```
m = df.gt(0)
m2 = m & (m.shift(1, fill_value=True) | m.shift(-1, fill_value=True))
df['sum'] =df.where(m2).sum(axis=1, min_count=1)
```

Or:

```
df['sum'] = df.where(df.gt(0).apply(lambda s: s & s.groupby((~s).cumsum())
                                    .transform('size').gt(2))
                    ).sum(axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   A  B  C   sum
0 -1  2 -1   2.0 # 2
1  3  2  5  10.0 # 3+2+5
2  6  8  4  18.0 # 6+8+4
3  4  7  7  18.0 # 4+7+7
4  3 -1  9  12.0 # 3+9
5 -1 -1 -1   NaN
6  1  3  5   NaN
7 -1 -1 -1   NaN
```

Comment: thank you so much. learned something new every time i asked a question here

Comment: You're welcome @unluckymonster. So to get the grand total, just add `sum()` to the final commands in the first approach.

Comment: Sorry to trouble you again. I tried the method you mentioned but it sum up all the data altogether. How to get another row at column sum every time the condition is met?

Comment: @unluckymonster is the provided output complete? If not, please edit it to have the full expected output. Also explain how you get `16`.

Comment: yes. the output is complete. 46 is the sum of row 2,3,4 and 16 is the sum of row 9, 10 since these 2 groups fulfil the condition [consecutive rows contains only positive values]. Sorry about my bad explanation. @mozway